# A neccessary edit? (whitespaces before KB/MB/GB/etc)

Tags: discussion, editing

If this [edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/420451/4) had gone through a review, it would probably be rejected as "`too minor`" (there, I "misused backticks" again).

What gives?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, is there really only one way to write file size suffixes? Not even Google gives a clear answer:

- ["4 GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%224%20GB%22), 110 million hits.
- ["4GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%224GB%22), 320 million hits.
- ["256 GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22256%20GB%22), 6 million hits.
- ["256GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22256GB%22), 19 million hits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit wasn't *only* about whitespace. It corrected two things:

- Anything that's not a shell command or some kind of code `should not be in backticks`. The `Erase free space` should have probably been *Erase free space* or "Erase free space". Folks really don't like to see this, as it distracts from the content and is just syntactically wrong.
- Unit suffixes should be spaced. This is the norm for SI units, and while GB etc. aren't SI units, the same could apply here. But editing a post just to change from "4GB" to "4 GB" would be unnecessary.

The rules for "too minor" edits are less strict for users with edit privileges. We review edits for users <2k to have them work hard for their privilege, but after that, minor edits are fine unless they come in masses.

Even if a little minor, the edit shouldn't have been rolled back.

Comment: I agree on the backticks, I should have found a better way to highlight the mentioned function. However, file sizes with/without spaces is not that simple: ["4 GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%224%20GB%22),  110 m hits. ["4GB"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%224GB%22), 320 m hits.

Comment: SI units [should always be spaced](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html), except for angular degrees. Granted, GB aren't SI units, but still. Maybe the majority has it wrong? :) (Though the real issue here for me is the `backticks`, honestly).

Comment: I agree on the SI units, that's the way it should be, but I follow what other people are using when it comes to MB:s and GB:s, as I'm using it everyday at my work when I discuss stuff with hardware vendors. They are not doing it differently. I'm guessing that people are treating MB as a SI unit as well, which it isn't.

Comment: Yes, and if somebody edited a question just to change the spacing between non-standardized unit suffixes, it'd be questionable. But to tell the truth: We have no style guide here on SU. Just apply common sense—I don't think it's such a big deal. The `random` word `highlights` are more problematic.

Comment: I agree on both. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @TFM Quick comment on that edit of mine (didn't see this meta post until now). For any non-scientific writing I usually refer to Wikipedia's Manual of Style for guidance; [it recommends a space between values and unit symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:MOSNUM#Unit_symbols), and not just for SI units. Admittedly, this is a bit of a pet peeve of mine and I tend to correct this when copyediting posts, but in this case, as **slhck** explained, the main point of the edit was to remove the misuse of backticks. I agree that on its own the whitespace change would have been too minor.

Comment: @Indrek:  I must admit that the usage of Wikipedia's Manual of Style is very (very) wise. However, I deal with many representatives from major hardware vendors. Nothing we and they write includes space between MBs and GBs. I dare NOT to change that. But I'm fine with your edit.